# ¿Como leer filas y columnas en este archivo .txt", donde las filas estan separadas por ";" y las columnas por ","?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, txt

Quiero leer este archivo mediante la libreria pandas y generar un dataframe. El dataframe deberia contener 4 columnas, de manera que cada "," indica una columna distinta, y cada ";" indica una fila distinta. No se como leer el fichero para generar el dataframe correspondiente.

El archivo .txt contiene lo siguiente:

822,100,33,33; 321,143,33,33; 367,236,33,33; 775,292,33,33; 951,492,33,33; 1153,518,33,33; 939,738,33,33; 988,702,33,33; 936,686,33,33; 946,647,33,33; 965,613,33,33; 900,636,33,33; 924,607,33,33; 936,565,33,33; 533,635,33,33; 515,570,33,33; 618,653,33,33; 669,620,33,33; 721,614,33,33; 759,614,33,33; 739,573,33,33; 774,576,33,33; 816,573,33,33; 851,551,33,33; 767,533,33,33; 852,475,33,33; 797,375,33,33; 704,512,33,33; 743,435,33,33; 807,446,33,33; 719,475,33,33; 638,503,33,33; 622,475,33,33; 704,409,33,33; 658,434,33,33; 660,394,33,33; 605,427,33,33; 595,397,33,33; 559,404,33,33; 577,424,33,33; 556,464,33,33; 537,434,33,33; 522,420,33,33; 479,420,33,33; 467,445,33,33; 479,504,33,33; 423,462,33,33; 431,492,33,33; 422,523,33,33; 394,558,33,33; 360,576,33,33; 363,603,33,33; 401,622,33,33; 441,631,33,33; 240,456,33,33; 287,435,33,33; 346,390,33,33; 313,338,33,33; 364,341,33,33; 411,341,33,33; 408,389,33,33; 442,280,33,33; 482,291,33,33; 521,331,33,33; 556,327,33,33; 574,287,33,33; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33; 822,100,33,33; 321,143,33,33; 367,236,33,33; 775,292,33,33; 951,492,33,33; 1153,518,33,33; 939,738,33,33; 988,702,33,33; 936,686,33,33; 946,647,33,33; 965,613,33,33; 900,636,33,33; 924,607,33,33; 936,565,33,33; 533,635,33,33; 515,570,33,33; 618,653,33,33; 669,620,33,33; 721,614,33,33; 759,614,33,33; 739,573,33,33; 774,576,33,33; 816,573,33,33; 851,551,33,33; 767,533,33,33; 852,475,33,33; 797,375,33,33; 704,512,33,33; 743,435,33,33; 807,446,33,33; 719,475,33,33; 638,503,33,33; 622,475,33,33; 704,409,33,33; 658,434,33,33; 660,394,33,33; 605,427,33,33; 595,397,33,33; 559,404,33,33; 577,424,33,33; 556,464,33,33; 537,434,33,33; 522,420,33,33; 479,420,33,33; 467,445,33,33; 479,504,33,33; 423,462,33,33; 431,492,33,33; 422,523,33,33; 394,558,33,33; 360,576,33,33; 363,603,33,33; 401,622,33,33; 441,631,33,33; 240,456,33,33; 287,435,33,33; 346,390,33,33; 313,338,33,33; 364,341,33,33; 411,341,33,33; 408,389,33,33; 442,280,33,33; 482,291,33,33; 521,331,33,33; 556,327,33,33; 574,287,33,33; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33; 822,100,33,33; 321,143,33,33; 367,236,33,33; 775,292,33,33; 951,492,33,33; 1153,518,33,33; 939,738,33,33; 988,702,33,33; 936,686,33,33; 946,647,33,33; 965,613,33,33; 900,636,33,33; 924,607,33,33; 936,565,33,33; 533,635,33,33; 515,570,33,33; 618,653,33,33; 669,620,33,33; 721,614,33,33; 759,614,33,33; 739,573,33,33; 774,576,33,33; 816,573,33,33; 851,551,33,33; 767,533,33,33; 852,475,33,33; 797,375,33,33; 704,512,33,33; 743,435,33,33; 807,446,33,33; 719,475,33,33; 638,503,33,33; 622,475,33,33; 704,409,33,33; 658,434,33,33; 660,394,33,33; 605,427,33,33; 595,397,33,33; 559,404,33,33; 577,424,33,33; 556,464,33,33; 537,434,33,33; 522,420,33,33; 479,420,33,33; 467,445,33,33; 479,504,33,33; 423,462,33,33; 431,492,33,33; 422,523,33,33; 394,558,33,33; 360,576,33,33; 363,603,33,33; 401,622,33,33; 441,631,33,33; 240,456,33,33; 287,435,33,33; 346,390,33,33; 313,338,33,33; 364,341,33,33; 411,341,33,33; 408,389,33,33; 442,280,33,33; 482,291,33,33; 521,331,33,33; 556,327,33,33; 574,287,33,33; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33; 822,100,33,33; 321,143,33,33; 367,236,33,33; 775,292,33,33; 951,492,33,33; 1153,518,33,33; 939,738,33,33; 988,702,33,33; 936,686,33,33; 946,647,33,33; 965,613,33,33; 900,636,33,33; 924,607,33,33; 936,565,33,33; 533,635,33,33; 515,570,33,33; 618,653,33,33; 669,620,33,33; 721,614,33,33; 759,614,33,33; 739,573,33,33; 774,576,33,33; 816,573,33,33; 851,551,33,33; 767,533,33,33; 852,475,33,33; 797,375,33,33; 704,512,33,33; 743,435,33,33; 807,446,33,33; 719,475,33,33; 638,503,33,33; 622,475,33,33; 704,409,33,33; 658,434,33,33; 660,394,33,33; 605,427,33,33; 595,397,33,33; 559,404,33,33; 577,424,33,33; 556,464,33,33; 537,434,33,33; 522,420,33,33; 479,420,33,33; 467,445,33,33; 479,504,33,33; 423,462,33,33; 431,492,33,33; 422,523,33,33; 394,558,33,33; 360,576,33,33; 363,603,33,33; 401,622,33,33; 441,631,33,33; 240,456,33,33; 287,435,33,33; 346,390,33,33; 313,338,33,33; 364,341,33,33; 411,341,33,33; 408,389,33,33; 442,280,33,33; 482,291,33,33; 521,331,33,33; 556,327,33,33; 574,287,33,33; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33; 822,100,33,33; 321,143,33,33; 367,236,33,33; 775,292,33,33; 951,492,33,33; 1153,518,33,33; 939,738,33,33; 988,702,33,33; 936,686,33,33; 946,647,33,33; 965,613,33,33; 900,636,33,33; 924,607,33,33; 936,565,33,33; 533,635,33,33; 515,570,33,33; 618,653,33,33; 669,620,33,33; 721,614,33,33; 759,614,33,33; 739,573,33,33; 774,576,33,33; 816,573,33,33; 851,551,33,33; 767,533,33,33; 852,475,33,33; 797,375,33,33; 704,512,33,33; 743,435,33,33; 807,446,33,33; 719,475,33,33; 638,503,33,33; 622,475,33,33; 704,409,33,33; 658,434,33,33; 660,394,33,33; 605,427,33,33; 595,397,33,33; 559,404,33,33; 577,424,33,33; 556,464,33,33; 537,434,33,33; 522,420,33,33; 479,420,33,33; 467,445,33,33; 479,504,33,33; 423,462,33,33; 431,492,33,33; 422,523,33,33; 394,558,33,33; 360,576,33,33; 363,603,33,33; 401,622,33,33; 441,631,33,33; 240,456,33,33; 287,435,33,33; 346,390,33,33; 313,338,33,33; 364,341,33,33; 411,341,33,33; 408,389,33,33; 442,280,33,33; 482,291,33,33; 521,331,33,33; 556,327,33,33; 574,287,33,33; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33;

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el parámetro `lineterminator` de `pandas.read_csv` para que se considere el carácter `;` como fin de linea.

Hay no obstante hay un problema, sobra el `;` final del archivo:

```
...; 533,257,33,33; 611,336,33,33; 836,1109,33,33; 
                                                 ^
                                                 ^
                                  Deberías arder en el infierno :)
```

Esto hace que se espere una nueva columna y el parser falla al considerar el `\n` final como dato de la primera columna (moraleja: no se usa un separador si no hay nada que separar). Puedes eliminarlo manualmente o cargar el archivo en memoria entero previamente y eliminarlo con `str.strip`.

Sería muy fácil de solucionar usando el parámetro `skipfooter` pero por desgracia el motor de Python no implementa a día de hoy `lineterminator` y el parser de C que si lo implementa no implementa `skipfooter`... perfecto...

```
import io

import pandas as pd


with open("/ruta/arcivo.txt") as file:
    data = io.StringIO(file.read().strip())

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", header=None,lineterminator=";")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>        0     1   2   3
> 0    822   100  33  33
> 1    321   143  33  33
> 2    367   236  33  33
> 3    775   292  33  33
> 4    951   492  33  33
> ..   ...   ...  ..  ..
> 340  556   327  33  33
> 341  574   287  33  33
> 342  533   257  33  33
> 343  611   336  33  33
> 344  836  1109  33  33
>
> [345 rows x 4 columns]
>
> >>> df.dtypes
> 0    int64
> 1    int64
> 2    int64
> 3    int64
> dtype: object
> ```

Comment: Perfecto. Funciona. Muchisimas gracias!